# Help creating zsh plugin that changes text in command line by pressing keybinding

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a zsh plugin that will replace the text of path  under  the
cursor when the user press a keybinding  (like `<ctrl-p>`). After  pressing  the
keybinding, I need to get the file path under cursor (1), pass it  to  a  custom
program I wrote (2), and replace the old text with the output of that program(3).

I need help with the ZSH stuff; the program itself is working. I never  wrote  a
zsh plugin, so I don't know where to start.

Here is how the program works: it takes a shortened version of a path and tries
to expand it to match files and directories:

```
[~]$ expandpath pic/w/n/m
pictures/wallpapers/nature/mountains.jpg
```

The program is basically  a  shell  script  I  wrote  myself.  It  accepts  both
absolute and relative paths, then expands them.

### Context

My goal is to boost productivity on the command line because  often  I  need  to
supply path of files as argument to other programs, and sometimes **those  files
are not under the current working directory  which  means  that  FZF  completion
won't work since FZF file completion uses the  current  directory  and  not  the
directory of the file under cursor, which may be absolute or relative paths**.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but zsh has no problems tab-completing `/something/pic/w/n/m` to `/something/pictures/wallpapers/nature/mountains.jpg` in its default configuration (after `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit`).

Comment: Hmm, that is indeed true... I didn't know that.. But this only works for certain commands such as mv, cp, (which are commands that ZSH knows that they expect a file argument). Moreover, the ZSH completion only works if the shortened versions of the path start with the same  letters of the real path. For example, ZSH won't exapnd something/iures/paper/ture/ to something/pictures/wallpaper/nature, but my program does expand

Comment: No, Zsh’s completion system doesn’t do that out of the box, but it can be configured to do so. Look for `matcher-list` in this section of the manual:  https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles